# HTML Special Characters Post as ASCII

Tags: php, html, utf-8, ascii

Please forgive me, I am new here. I hope I have formatted this correctly. I have converted a database from ASCII to UTF-8 changing all of the Special Characters. `Example â changed to &acirc;`

Working Example:
Domaine Comte Georges de Vogüé

changed to,

`Domaine Comte Georges de Vog&uuml;&eacute;`

In my HTML page I have a form with the line below as one of the options.

```
<option>Domaine Comte Georges de Vog&uuml;&eacute;</option>
```

When the form is posted to the PHP page the value is changed to

```
Domaine Comte Georges de Vogüé
```

So when it is searched for in the database of course it is not found.

The options for the dropdown field are generated dynamically using code I found at [So You Need To Fill a Dropdown Dynamically https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/]

How do I keep the option value from changing when posted to the PHP script?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: You should not store HTML entities in the database - store UTF-8 encoded raw data.

Comment: Obviously. I was referring to displaying.

Comment: Also converting a database from ASCII to UTF-8 does not involve html entities.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a value to the option?

```
<option value="Domaine Comte Georges de Vog&uuml;&eacute;">Domaine Comte Georges de Vog&uuml;&eacute;</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the HTML entities as displayed on the page (ü, é, etc.) to their representative values prior to performing the database search; this can be accomplished using the PHP function html_entity_decode() -- for example:

```
<?php
print html_entity_decode('Domaine Comte Georges de Vog&uuml;&eacute;');
?>
```

Will result in an output of --

> Domaine Comte Georges de Vogüé

More information, options, and examples of usage can be found within the PHP manual -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php